# Linq outer join using inequality?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

In SQL I'd say:

```
select a.*
from TableA a 
left join TableB b on a.Type = b.Type and a.SomeDate < b.AnotherDate
where b.ID is null
```

This would select all records in TableA where no record exists in TableB of the same `Type` and later date.

In Linq, how do you do this?

```
from a in TableA
join b in TableB on a.Type equals b.Type into j // what about the comparator?
from x in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
where x == null
select a;
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

A few good answers have been proposed, all of which address the specific need expressed in this question, but they're all basically workarounds.  They all translate to a nested "exists" queries in one way or another, whereas the SQL in the question is one neat query without any nesting.  The case given here is just an example of a general principle; what I'd really like to see is a Linq expression that will translate to (roughly) the syntax of the above SQL query.

Comment: That's not inequality but a Comparison (less-than).

Comment: An "Exists query" is actually the solution and the better implementation for the query specified.

Comment: Try to see the execution plan of the my query below. "left join" or "nested query" is implementation details and syntax differences.

Comment: @Magnus/@_FRED_ - interesting - is that what always happens internally  when you do an outer join like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = TableA.Where(a => 
                 !TableB.Any(b => a.Type == b.Type && a.Date < b.Date))
```

If you want the linq query to be exactly as your SQL you can write:

```
var result = from a in TableA
             from b in TableB.Where(b => a.Type = b.Type && a.SomeDate < b.AnotherDate).DefaultIfEmpty()
             where b == null
             select a;
```

But I would say that the first solution is better as the `where b == null` would result in a filter operation in the queryplan.

Comment: Thank you for all your explanations - you pipped @_FRED_ to the post... :)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this ought to help:

```
var results = 
    (from itemA in TableA
    from itemB in TableB
    where itemA.Type != itemB.Type && itemA.Date < itemB.Date
    select itemA).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from a in tableA
let rights =
  from b in tableB
  where a.Type == b.Type && a.Date < b.Date
  select b
where !rights.Any()
select a;
```

It's translated into:

```
SELECT [t0].[Type] AS [Type], [t0].[SomeDate] AS [SomeDate]
FROM [TableA] AS [t0]
WHERE NOT (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [TableB] AS [t1]
    WHERE ([t0].[Type] = [t1].[Type]) AND ([t0].[SomeDate] < [t1].[AnotherDate])))
```

Comment: Whoever voted this down - 'twould have been nice if you'd explained why...?